# Android Periodic Sensor Data

Tags: java, android

For an Android App, that will show the value of an internal sensor (e.g. Acceleration) in a graph, i need to find a way to access this signal periodically.
At the moment i am using a `SensorEventListener`, but unfortunately this only gives me the possibility to get a value whenever it changes. 
Since I want to display the graph (point to point) in dependency of the time, this means it would directly draw a line from the old to the new value (and if the old value has been a long time, it looks like a linear changing of the value).
So my question: How can I get access to a sensor's data periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)) says that `registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor int)`

"Registers a SensorEventListener for the given sensor at the given sampling frequency."

To get these events, though, your application would need to be active (hold a partial wake lock). It would be better to do this in a background service so that the application doesn't need to remain active. See for example, [SensorEventListener in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598314/sensoreventlistener-in-a-service)

Comment: The problem with this is, that the time is only a suggestion to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate.
This means,
`registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor int, 1000000)` 
(1 million µs = 1s) does not generate one value each second, but many many more.
So what can I do to - for example - receive a sensor signal each second?

Comment: Keep track of the time when you got the last readingbthat you were interested in, and just don't do anything with readings that come in within less than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

So in the end i used a timer, which checked the values from my sensor, which I put into an array, periodically. 
Unfortunately `registerListener` didnt work, since the value is just a suggestion for the system. 
Thanks though for the help.